# Uncompile Development Asset Pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I was compiling my asset pipeline for my production environment and it did for all my environments. How can I uncompile my asset pipeline for my development environment?

I have checked my config/development environment and cannot find a fix.

Thanks in advance for any help...

Answer (score 90, accepted):

To remove precompiled assets use:

```
rake assets:clean
```

What this basically does is remove the `public/assets` directory. You may need to include the `RAILS_ENV` variable if you need to run it for a certain environment.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I had to issue `RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake assets:clean`.

Comment: also, be sure to clear your browser cache. even after you've restarted your server, the pages served up may still include a cached copy of the compiled application.js file

Comment: Neither worked here, had to remove the entire `public/assets` folder.

Comment: Did you put this line in your application.js '//= require_tree .' and this line in application.css '*= require_tree .' You need to to it.

Comment: Or just remove your folder public/assets

Comment: I'm not sure why they changed the syntax for Rails 4 to rake assets:clobber

Answer (score 45):

Try using

```
rake assets:clobber
```

worked for me in rails 4

Comment: Care to explain why this works? Until then I cannot vote up your answer and frankly few people will, SO answers should help people understand the issue not just provide a line of code.

Comment: It deletes compiled assets. You can also manually remove them, this is just a shortcut.

Answer (score 5):

When you run the compile task locally (on your development machine) the assets are compiled in the Rails production environment, but are written to the public folder.

This means that even when you run in development mode it'll use the compiled assets instead of sending requests to the pipeline. This is normal behavor - requests only go to the pipeline if the file does not exists in `public/assets`.

The compile task should generally only be used when deploying, and on the remote (production) machine.

If you have compiled locally, you can delete all the files in the `public/assets` folder and development will behave as before. If you checked these files into source control you'll need to remove them.

Once removed things should work fine.
s
One final tip: if this is an upgraded app check your config settings against those in the [last section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#upgrading-from-old-versions-of-rails) of the Rails asset pipeline guide.

Comment: At least this answer doesn't just provide a one line code answer, but attempts to explain.

Answer (score 5):

For Rails 5:

```
$ RAILS_ENV=development bin/rake assets:clobber
```